# Soap Webservice ProtocolException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I have following Problem:

I need to implement a SOAP Web Service to a ASP.NET Webpage.
The webservice was bought from another company so I don't have access to it.

When I try to call a Function called "IsAlive" it should return the String "Server is running" but instead I get the following Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException was not handled by user code.
   HResult = -2146233079
   Message = The request content type found by the client is' multipart / related; type = "application / xml + xop"; boundary = "uuid: *"; start = ""; start-info = "application / soap + xml" ', expected to be' application / soap + xml '.

### Error in the request with the following error message:

--uuid: *
Content-Type: application / xop + xml; charset = UTF-8; type = "application / soap + xml"
Content transfer encoding: binary
Content ID:

http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">    server is running